# Restrict view to only be accessible by App Engine internal network

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I would like to find a way to restrict a view (request handler) to only be called from within the Google App Engine internal network from within my view and not within app.yaml.

For example, I have a view to handle inbound email within my Flask application

```
@app.route('/_ah/mail/notifications@example.appspotmail.com', methods=['POST'])
def inbound_notification_email():
    from google.appengine.api import mail
    message = mail.InboundEmailMessage(request.data)
    ...
    return '' # 200 OK
```

While I know I could put all my mail handlers in their own file / wsgi instance like so:

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: inbound_mail.app
  login: admin
```

I would prefer not to have to do this as I'm using Flask instead of Webapp.  Right now the request works as setup above, but it is exposed to the world.

Inspecting the request to my `inbound_notification_email()` view, I see `X-App-Country` in the request header is set to `ZZ` and the request's remote address is `0.1.0.20`.  I know the 0.x.x.x IP range is IANA reserved for local networks so it seems logical that checking if request.remote_address starts with "0." would work, but I'm not sure if all internal requests within App Engine are always handled this way (push queues and xmpp come to mind).

One thing I was surprised to see was `users.is_current_user_admin()` returns False within `inbound_notification_mail()` even though you're to set `login: admin` when using Webapp.

Comment: login admin means that only app admin can access the handler, not that whom ever access the handler is an admin.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @yoonjesung I did not find a solution to this

Comment: @SeanLynch Not sure if relevant now, but was wondering if you could use App Engine's app identity for this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/

Comment: @yoonjesung possibly, but I've been away from the project using this for a while now.  I've been using Node.js and App Engine Flexible environment more recently.